# PHP 7.3 -> function_exists: mystery working the 'function_exists'

Tags: php, php-7

Why does it **only first example not work**? What does it happen with the function_exists if it under array_walk?
Is it working compiler so, php stack, scope?

I didn't found any explain about it. Or may be I found but didn't understand.

1. It doesn't work and throw exception:
   Warning: array_walk() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'test_print' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/sandbox.php on line 4

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
if(!function_exists('test_print')) {
    function test_print($item2, $key)
    {
        echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
    }
}
```

2. It works

```
<?php 
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

if(!function_exists('test_print')) {
    function test_print($item2, $key)
    {
        echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
    }
}
array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
```

3. It works

```
<?php 
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

   function test_print($item2, $key)
   {
       echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
   }

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
```

4. It works

```
<?php 
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
     echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
}
```

[php sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/) if you need

Comment: It's because you're trying to use it before it's defined.

Comment: Why do you expect the function to work if it doesn't exist yet? Though, the last example is curious

Comment: From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php): *Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, **except when a function is conditionally defined** as shown in the two examples below.*

Comment: @iainn thank you much. I understood at last.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Last example works due to hoisting. Non-conditional function definitions are moved to the top of their scope before execution.